# Is there a way to load a .json configuration file and automatically substitute environment variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, docker-compose

I'm a little new to the javascript ecosystem, so apologies if I'm asking the question wrong.

I'm working on a legacy project that loads configuration files from .json files. In those .json files there are variables that need to be substituted with environment variables.

For example
config.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "host": "%DBHOST%",
    "port": "%DBPORT%"
  }
}
```

In the legacy code, there are complicated startup scripts that use `sed` to do variable substitution. I'm moving the project into docker and would much rather define DBHOST/DBPORT etc in the docker definitions and have it magically update the configuration. Right now, I just have docker running a script that does the `sed` operation which works, but this feels clunky. Is there a way I can tell node to load the .json file and automatically substitute the `%VAR%` blocks with an environment variable if there is a match?

Answer (score 0):

With NodeJS you can load an environment variable like this:

```
process.env.VARIABLE_NAME
```